# REAL domain detecting php

Tags: php, dns, subdomain

I need to detect real domain name, without sub domain.

```
example.com
example.com.ua
sub.example.com.ua
sub.example.com
```

`com.ua` - third level domain name.
For `com.ua` domain my result must be `example.com.ua`,
for others - `example.com`

Now my code looks like

```
$domain = parse_url($domain, PHP_URL_HOST);
$domain = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $domain), -2));
```

But it don't recognize subdomain and third level domain name. And for `com.ua` domain names return `com.ua`

Comment: Please explain in brief what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understood what you are saying but i think you want to detect the current domain is subdomain or not. For this purpose use the code below

```
 <?php
    $sub ="sub";
    $a=explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    $check = array_shift($a);
    if($check==$sub)
    {
    echo "this is a subdomain"."<br>";
    foreach($a as $test)
{
$main_domain.=$test;
}
echo "The main domain is:".$main_domain;
    }

    else
    {
    echo "This is not a sub domain";
    }
    ?>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like, it will return you sub from below example

```
$url = 'http://sub.example.com.ua';
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);
$host = explode('.', $parsedUrl['host']);
$subdomain = $host[0];
echo $subdomain;
```

Comment: I need get main domain. From you code I can get just first part, so if domain `example.com.ua` I would get `example`, but it is a main domain, not sub.

Comment: Try to Print_r($host), you will get below elements in array Array ( [0] => sub [1] => example [2] => com [3] => ua )

Comment: Yes. But if `$url='http://example.com.ua'`, Array ([0] => example [1] => com [2] => ua). But `example` not a subdomain, it is a main third level domain.

Comment: You can write logic i.e. if array count is 4 means, you have to  concat string last 3 items , if its 3 then concat last 2 items, if 2 count then concat last two items

Comment: Array can be 4, 5, 6 etc :) I found solution.

Comment: Good, Don't forget to accept answer, if above answer helped :)

Answer (score -1):

```
function domain($domain) 
{ 
    $parts = explode('.', $domain); 
    $idz = count($parts); 
    $idz -= 3; 

    if(strlen($parts[($idz+2)]) == 2)
    { 
        $domain = $parts[$idz].'.'.$parts[($idz+1)].'.'.$parts[($idz+2)]; 
    } 
    else if(strlen($parts[($idz+2)]) == 0)
    { 
        $domain = $parts[($idz)].'.'.$parts[($idz+1)]; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $domain = $parts[($idz+1)].'.'.$parts[($idz+2)]; 
    }

    return $domain; 
} 

$domain = 'sub1.sub2.sub3.example.com.ua';
echo domain($domain);
```

Return: example.com.ua.
It is REAL domain name.